# Aperiodic bijections preserving non-principal ultrafilters

Tags: set-theory, logic, dynamical-systems

Assume that $X$ is a set and $\mathcal F$ is a non-principal ultrafilter on $X$. A bijection $\varphi\colon X\to X$ is *$|X|$-aperiodic* if the set
$$
\text{Per}(\varphi)=\{x\in X:\exists n\ge 1 \,\varphi^n(x)=x\}
$$
has strictly smaller cardinality than $X$ (i.e. $\text{card}(\text{Per}(\varphi))<\text{card}(X)$).

Does there exist an aperiodic bijection $\varphi\colon X\to X$ that *preseves* $\mathcal{F}$ in the following sense
$$ 
F\in\mathcal{F} \text{ if and only if }\varphi(F)\in\mathcal{F}?
$$

Comment: It follows from the lemma on three sets that a bijection $\varphi\colon X\to X$ preserves an ultrafilter $\mathcal F$ if and only if $\{x\in X:\varphi(x)=x\}\in \mathcal F$.

Comment: I'd call this $|X|$-aperiodic: aperiodic rather means that $\mathrm{Per}(\varphi)$ is empty. Anyway Emil's remark completely answers the question (I didn't know the mentioned lemma but the verification of the fact is easy — a restatement is that for every permutation of $X$, the set of points it fixes in $\beta X$ is open).

Comment: Migrated on request from OP.